# Validation message on Login form not shown

Tags: authentication-authorization

On /user/login, when I forget to enter the login credentials, and click on the submission button, no error message is shown as expected.

What problem might be causing this?

Comment: try the same thing with the default theme in drupal. it might be something theme related. if not, you may overrided the validation callback somehow. you can try disabling custom/contrib modules just in case some of them are doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the form id for login form. and then try [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in any custom module.

Add a submit callback or validation callback in which you can check for the empty fields yourself. According use `drupal_set_message()` to display the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply piyuesh. Will give a try and let you know.